# Page content refreshing before navigating in Xamarin Forms with Prism

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mvvm, prism

During my navigation with "Hamburger menu" in `Prism.Forms` (`Master Detail Page`), my currently selected page I navigate from acts weirdly like it is refreshed/reseted. In this specific page I have "boolen rendering" in `XAML` where I play with `IsVisible` property. There is scenario where I should see only some PNG covering content beneath, but when I navigate with Hamburger, PNG disappears and I can see the content I shouldn't for a moment. It looks like property bindings are off or something. `CollectionViews` underneath PNG are empty, everything looks like in Visual Studio Xaml Preview during coding where `XAML` has no idea about bindings, it just shows everything with default content.

The `XAML` of this Page (`MainPage.xaml`) looks like this:

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
            <Image Source="nfc.png" IsVisible="{Binding IsFirstRead}" BackgroundColor="White" />
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="NotFirstRead" Command="{Binding NotFirstReadCommand}" />

            <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsFirstRead, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolean}}" 
                            Opacity="{Binding IsFirstRead, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToDigit}}" 
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Row="0" Text="{Static resources:Strings.Button_WriteTag}" Command="{Binding WriteTagCommand}" />
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="FirstRead" Command="{Binding FirstReadCommand}" />

                <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding FrontControlsCollection}" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding MemoryMapItem.Name}" />
                                <Entry Text="{Binding NewValue}" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                    <Entry.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding MemoryMapItem.DataType}" Value="{Static dt:DataType.Int}">
                                            <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="Numeric" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Entry.Triggers>
                                </Entry>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>

                <CollectionView Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding MifarePagesCollection}" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding RecordView}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>

            </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

`XAML` of the root (MDP):

```
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu">
            <StackLayout Padding="20">
                <Button Text="{Static resources:Strings.Label_Home }" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="NavigationPage/MainPage" />
                <Button Text="{Static resources:Strings.Label_Language}" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="NavigationPage/LanguagePage" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Root `VM`:

```
    public class RootPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private DelegateCommand<string> _navigateCommand;

        public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand => _navigateCommand ??= new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteNavigateCommand);

        private async void ExecuteNavigateCommand(string uri)
        {
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(uri);
        }

        public RootPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Here is the video showing the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z5htYQrznG86C67AmBJ8hCl9_x_FzN88/view?usp=sharing

You can even see here that PNG does not really disappear but more like its `z-index` is lower than everything's else (you can see it between elements).

Comment: Very interesting.... I see similar problems with a tabbed layout (also using Prism)...

Comment: Exactly. Friend of mine is using tabbed layout as you do and he has the same problem

Comment: What is he considering to do to fix it? I have considered trying out Shell with tabs - but not sure if it is quite production ready yet....? Also considered Sharpnado - but that seems to be a larger refactoring that I haven't done yet just to try out if it works better....